# Hyperbolic, parabolic and elliptic PDEs behavior relationship with Conic sections

Tags: partial-differential-equations, conic-sections, elliptic-equations, hyperbolic-equations, parabolic-pde

Besides the well know relationship in terms of the discriminant of a 2nd order polynomial, is there any else that relates in some sense the behavior of 2nd order PDEs (better, its solution) with the "geometrical shape" of the corresponding conic section?

I mean, given the well known geometrical symmetries of conic sections, is there any relationship with the underneath underneath symmetries of these PDEs solutions, e.g. the  time reversal symmetry of hyperbolic PDEs solution (waves propagation) or the irreversibility of parabolic PDEs solution (diffusion process)? What about elliptic PDEs solution which does not depend upon time, at all?

I cannot withstand this is merely a fact of semantics/terminology. Isn't it?

If so, one might think about these particular kind of PDEs solutions as the "intersection" between two functional spaces? What would the "conic surface" functional space stand for? What about the "plane"?

Comment: The way I see it is that a hyperbola goes to infinity in both directions, a parabola goes to infinity in one direction, and an ellipse doesn't reach infinity at all.

Comment: I like this answer it was the only one that popped-up to my mind! There might be anything else, such as a the respective "roles" of abscissa and ordinate for conic sections, with respect to space and time for PDEs?